# How to get printer PHYSICALOFFSETX with script

Tags: winapi, vbscript, wmi, wsh, printers

Actually I need a script to return all of these :

```
PHYSICALOFFSETX (112)
PHYSICALOFFSETY (113) 
PHYSICALWIDTH (110) 
PHYSICALHEIGHT (111)
```

I started with the python win32ui built into eventghost, but that failed due to a dependency I can't fix. Every installation in my building has the same problem, too. So, after installing every version I could of MS Visual C++ Redistributables with no luck, I reverted to WMI, which returns EVERYTHING but those. So I took a swing at VBS and WSH, both unfruitful. I can't use Powershell.

Can you either point out what I'm missing, or perhaps lead me onto a different route?

Comment: `PHYSICALOFFSETX` is a constant which is 112. Maybe you need `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALOFFSETX)` See the function [`GetDeviceCaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Ok , thanks... My question is how to do that with a script of some sort. Python would use win32ui, which is broken in the dependencies.